# How can i find and display a record that contains a piece of data found using an algorithm in python

Tags: python, arrays, record

What I would like to be able to do is ask the user for how many cities they would like to enter, then the user inputs the data about these cities, this all works fine. One of the pieces of data that the user inputs is the population. I would like to find the minimum population all of the cities and then all of the data from that record that has the lowest population.

```
def createArray0fRecords(length):
  city_records = ["", "", 0.0,""]#Create record
  #City, Country, Population in Millions, Main Language

  city_array = [city_records]*length #Create Array of Records

  return city_array

def populateRecords(city_array):
  for counter in range (0, len(city_array)):
      print("")
      print("Please enter the city")
      city=input()

      print('Please enter the country')
      country=input()

      print("Please enter the population in millions")
      population=float(input())
      while population < 0:
        print(population," isn't a valid answer. Please input a number greater than 0.")
        population=input()
      print("Please enter the main language")
      language = input()

      city_array[counter] = [city, country, population, language]

  return city_array




def main_program():
  print("How many cities will you be entering?")
  length = int(input())
  city_array = createArray0fRecords(length)
  city_array = populateRecords(city_array)


  min = city_array[2]
  for i in range(len(city_array)):
    if min < city_array[i]:
      min = city_array[i]

  relevant_cities = [c for c in city_array if c[2] == min]
  print(relevant_cities[min])

main_program()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `city_records` is not just a list, it's a  list of lists. So instead of `min = city_array[2]`, write this `min = city_array[0][2]`.
Since  we  are assigning `0` index as minimum, we should start the loop with `1` index.

```
min = city_array[0][2]
for i in range(1,len(city_array)):
    if min > city_array[i][2]:
        min = city_array[i][2]

relevant_cities = [c for c in city_array if c[2] == min]
print(relevant_cities)
```

Also, in your while loop of function `populateRecords`, you forgot to convert string to float `population=input()`-> `population=float(input())`